# Java - How to put the next column of a file into an array

Tags: java, arrays, file

Here is the file I am reading from:

```
>18  64  94  54  34  44
>40  26  26  92  96  34
>56  24  40  92  70  58
>92  72  12  46  46  56
>50  28  2  64  12  58
>98  28  40  88  86  20
>46  56  100  60  52  12
>82  70  98  18  50  30
>58  36  98  4  74  76
>76  28  72  74  74  60
```

Here is my code:

```
>package exercise;
>
>import java.io.File;
>import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
>import java.util.Scanner;
>
>public class Lab1 {
>
>   public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
>       
>       File file = new File("numberData.csv");
>       Scanner fileScan = new Scanner(file);
>       
>       int[] ND1Column1 = new int[10];
>       int[] ND1Column2 = new int[10];
>       int[] ND1Column3 = new int[10];
>       int[] ND1Column4 = new int[10];
>       int[] ND1Column5 = new int[10];
>       int[] ND1Column6 = new int[10];
>       int[] ND2Column1 = new int[16];
>       int[] ND2Column2 = new int[16];
>       int[] ND2Column3 = new int[16];
>       int[] ND2Column4 = new int[16];
>       
>       
>       for(int row = 0; row < 10; row++)
>       {
>           ND1Column1[row] = fileScan.nextInt();
>           fileScan.nextLine();
>       }
>       for(int row = 0; row < 10; row++)
>       {   
>           fileScan.nextInt();
>           ND1Column2[row] = fileScan.nextInt();
>           fileScan.nextLine();
>       }
>       
>       File file2 = new File("numberData2.csv");
>       Scanner fileScan2 = new Scanner(file);
>       
>       System.out.print(ND1Column2[0]);
>   }
```

I got the first column put into an array successfully. I just need to figure out how to put the following columns into their own array. The code I have here for my second for loop doesn't seem to do it correctly. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: _doesn't seem_ How can you tell?

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of the 2nd for() loop and merge the code into one nested for() loop.

You can also save a lot of code by reading the file into a 2-dimensional array, a matrix.  Here is how to write the matrix:

```
int[][] ND1Column = new int[6][10];
int[][] ND2Column = new int[16][10];

for (int row = 0; row < 6; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < 10; col++) {
        if (!fileScan.hasNextInt()) fileScan.nextLine();
        ND1Column[row][col] = fileScan.nextInt();
    }
}

//Do the same thing for ND2Column except give the array 16 cols and 4 rows
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("numberData.csv"));
String line;
int i = 0;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
   i++;
   switch(i):
   case 1:
      // put line inside ND1Column1
   case 2:
      // put line inside ND1Column2
   //etc
}
br.close();
```